# ClojureScript to Javascript : how to return nothing

Tags: clojurescript

I am using `ClojureScript` in an interoperability scenario, and I have a public function that is basically a `go` block. When I call it from my browser console, it returns a ClojureScript object (the result of `go`).

I would like to return nothing not even undefined (as in `return;`).
How do I do that ?

```
(defn :^export myFn [cb]
  (go ...)
  js/undefined) ;; what do I put here instead of js/undfined?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript a `return;` will return undefined:

```
(typeof (function() {return;})())
=> "undefined"
```

Hence your `js/undefined` is just fine.